# PHP script sample for iPhone hi-score/survey uploading?

Tags: php, iphone

I am looking for a PHP example/tutorial which can accept hi-scores/survey  upload from an iPhone. Hopefully, the PHP script:

- accepts POST, in additional to GET
- works over SSL (https)
- connects to MySQL

In addition, it'd best the iPhone can get a session from the server and submit the session value along with the hi-score. Thanks

Comment: Your #1 score will be 999999999 with the name `h@x0r` :D

Answer (score 1):

It's all HTML, you don't need anything special for the iPhone unless you're trying to tailor the looks. I've done almost the exact thing you're asking using Zend Framework and the iWebKit CSS library.

1. If you want sessions/user details create a login page
2. Create forms for submitting your relevant data
3. Create pages for displaying said data however you see fit.

Comment: When I try to open the link, my broswer shows: "Reported Attack Page!
This web page at iwebkit.net has been reported as an attack page and has been blocked based on your security preferences."

Comment: I checked on this as well and tried to alert the webmaster. The last time I checked it was fine, I guess their server was hacked for malware. I have removed the URL from my post.

Comment: Another framework is iui (http://code.google.com/p/iui/) though I have never used it.